# Does get_where() allow multiple parameters?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am passing a parameter from model to view like this

Model

```
class school_model extends CI_Model{

function employee_get($student_id){
$query = $this->db->get_where('students', array('student_id'=>$student_id));
return $query->row_array();
}

}
```

Controller

```
    function bret($student_id){
    $this->load->model('school_model');
    $data = $this->school_model->employee_get($student_id);
    echo $data['student_gender'];
    }
```

This obviously translates to `select * from students where id=id` given for example and seen through the browser like `http://example.com/env/at/index.php/frontpage/bret/306`

I am wondering if the `get_where()` is suitable if i wanted to have this query

`select student_gender,student_has_a_medical_condition  from students where (student_gender = 'female' && student_has_a_medical_condition = 'no') LIMIT 40;`

Will i need to extend `get_where()` for it to work?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,I suggest reading the excellent documentation for CodeIgniter on the [ActiveRecord](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) class.

You don't have to extend `get_where()` but just use the existing methods to define your query:

```
function employee_get($student_id){
$this->db->select('student_gender','student_has_a_medical_condition');
$query = $this->db->get_where('students', array('student_id'=>$student_id,'student_has_a_medical_condition'=>'no','student_gender'=>'female'),40);
return $query->row_array();
}
```

Of course you can pass in the additional parameters to the function so they are not hardcoded, and you can also pass in the desired columns as a paremeter, too. But start with the documentation.

Comment: I am hoping for urls such as `http://example.com/env/at/index.php/frontpage/bret/female/no/` Can this be done using extracting `uri` but using parameters only?.I hope you understand what i am saying.

Comment: Well you can add optional parameters to your `frontpage` controller `bret` method: `bret($student_id,$gender=null,$condition=null)` and then pass those to your model after a null test. Or you are you asking if you can detect those URI segments from within the model and use those as conditions?

Comment: Yes that is what i am asking.

Comment: The [URI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) class has excellent methods to parse the URL and is accessible from the model, so this is feasible. **But** this is *not* a good MVC practice from my perspective as this leads to hard to maintain code by putting application flow logic in the model. Ideally handle URI parsing in your controller and not in in the model.